# What Complexity Class Contains $QSAT_{\log n}$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, oracle-machines

It is known that $QSAT$ is $PSPACE$ complete, and it is known that $QSAT_i$ is $\Sigma_i$ complete for any constant $i$. However, what if we had $QSAT_{\log n}$? That is, $QSAT$ where the quantifiers can alternate $\omega(1)$ times, but still $o(n)$. Would this be enough to make the problem $PSPACE$ complete, or are all $O(n)$ alternations necessary? If this is not $PSPACE$ hard, would it fit somewhere in $PH$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Sigma_{O(\log n)} \mathrm{P}$ be the class of languages accepted by a polynomial-time alternative Turing machine with $O(\log n)$ alternations. Then, $QSAT_{\log n}$ is complete for this complexity class (under polynomial-time many-one reduction, for example). This question in TCS.SE [Quantified Boolean Formulas with logarithmic alternations](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37614/quantified-boolean-formulas-with-logarithmic-alternations) has some more discussions of this complexity class.

> If this is not PSPACE hard, would it fit somewhere in PH?

The problem is $PH$-hard because $QSAT_i$ is $\Sigma_{i+1}$-complete for every $i$ and we have $i \in O(\log n)$ for all constant $i$.